# PowerBI - Excel datasource contains JSON in column

Tags: json, excel, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have an excel sheet that has three columns **A**, **B** and **C**.

**A** and **B** contain regular text. A **firstname** and **lastname**, if you will. The third column **C** contains JSON data.

Is there a way I can read this file into PowerBI and have it automatically parse out the JSON data into additional columns? In PowerBI Desktop Client, I can use an excel sheet as the datasource, and it loads in my data into the client, however it naturally treats column **C** as just text. I've had a look at the Advanced Editor and I'm thinking I might have to include something in there to help parse that out.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the header do you see a couple of arrows in json column? If yes, click it.

Comment: No arrows, however I was able to right-click the column header and select "Transform -> JSON" and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In the query editor, right-click on the column that contains the JSON, go to **Transform** and select **JSON**. It will parse out the data, allowing you to add them in as additional column.

[image]

Extremely handy!